# Android project build with native libraries inside using maven

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-maven-plugin

I have an Android project with Maven that uses internal libraries. When I run a *maven install* the so library is not inside the jar file generated and in consequence is not inside the apk generated. I'm using Eclipse with maven and android maven plugin v.3.7.0.

My pom.xml is:

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>../bin/${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>15</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It seems that *nativeLibrariesDirectory* tag doesn't works for me.

Any idea to fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android for Maven Eclipse](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/) project doesn't yet support native libraries. If you'd like to see this supported please send a [pull request](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: This is no longer valid in the latest maven plugin; see my answer below for the correct pom entry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to include native libraries in your apk:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <manifest>
                    <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                </manifest>
                <!-- Where the native files are located; in the future we should use src/main/libs -->
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>                
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>alignApk</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>zipalign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```